# MS Excel: How to use format painter with just the keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2016

If you want to paste a format, you can copy and use the keyboard shortcut to paste special (Ctrl + Alt + V). MS Excel also has a useful format painter tool. You can select it using a keyboard shortcut (Using the hotkeys for the ribbon tools and then hitting the keys F, P).

However, what happens next is that the moment you move to a different cell using the arrow keys, it gets copied to that cell. With a mouse you can select any cell you want, but obviously with a keyboard it's going to be pasted onto one of the neighbouring cells:

[image]

How do I do this properly with just the keyboard? (I'm using Excel 2016)

Comment: Note that you can use the keyboard to finish the paste special: Ctrl+Alt+V Alt-T Enter. You could also do Shift-F10 F R to use the Context Menu to paste the formatting. Or do Ctrl-V Ctrl R (separate press and release of Control key to open Paste Context Menu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** (November 2020): This Method does not work in the current version of Excel, as it will copy both format and content of the origin cell. Unless you are formatting empty cells, I recommend using the [method of
WireGuy](https://superuser.com/a/1348007/220160) instead: Use `F5` or `Ctrl+G` to navigate to the target cell.

---

Original Answer: It is quite cumbersome, but after you undo (`Ctrl + z`) formatting the neighbouring cell, you can move around the cursor with the keyboard arrows and press `enter` finally to paint the correct cell.

If you hold down `shift` while navigating (before pressing `enter`) you can paint multiple (adjacent) cells at once.

Comment: This actually copies the entire cell around, including the conditional formatting. The OP wants to copy the conditional formatting only. It should not have been the answer.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up @Fandango68. I am not sure if Excel changed it's behaviour, or if we missed it back then as we happened to test it with empty cells. Either way, I updated the answer to reflect the fact that it is not working now.

Answer (score 6):

Press `F5` or `Ctrl+G` (Go To), and type in the address of your destination cell.
You can `F5` around and when you are done press `ESC` to get out of format painter.

Answer (score 1):

I use two options:

## 1 (For Office 365):

1- Select your desired cell to copy you format from.

2- Press Alt + H, then press F & P keys, (you just copied your last selected cell format).

3- just click with your mouse where do you want to paste the format.

## 2 (For older versions):

1- Press Ctrl + C on your desired cell to copy you format from.

2- Select your desired Cells you where you want to paste the format.

3- Press Alt + E, then S & T Keys, and Enter.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me, but @Vincent's answer gave me a clue. As per my comment above to Vincent, that technique actually copied the entire cell value, format and all. Sorry mate but I found another way:

1. Just select the cell(s) you want to copy *Conditional Formatting* from. Use the keyboard or mouse here. It doesn't matter.
2. Do what Vincent said using the `CTRL-Z` bit
3. Shift-Select and move the cursor over the cell(s)/range you want to copy the conditional formatting to (this was handy as I had over 12,000 rows and 150 colunms! No way I was going to do this with a mouse).
4. Instead of hitting `ENTER`, as Vincent suggested, go to *Paste Special*.
5. Select Paste --> Formats
6. Now press `ENTER`.

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:
First you have to **prepare** excel

1. You add "Paste formatting" to the quick access toolbar
   /customize quick access toolbar - more commands - choose commands from: all commands/
2. you need to know the number it has now (depending on the position you moved it) - it's 8 by me

After that you can **use** it like

3. copy the part you want to use the format from
4. navigate to the cells you want to use the format, press CTRL+Alt twice and after that the number

In my case this is: Ctrl+Alt , Alt , 8

It sounds complicated but it's pretty easy after repeating a couple of times

Answer (score 0):

Just to be more explicit on Fandango68's answer, which worked for me, the process is:

1. Select cell / range with format to be copied
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
3. Select cell / range where format is to be pasted
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd> > <kbd>H</kbd>  *Home* on the ribbon
5. <kbd>V</kbd> > <kbd>S</kbd> *Paste* drop down, then *Special*
6. <kbd>T</kbd> > <kbd>Enter</kbd> selects *Formats* in the *Paste Special* menu and applies it.

So the full sequence is to copy the cell whose format you want to paste with standard copy shortcut, move to the target cell, followed by the sequence:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> > <kbd>H</kbd> > <kbd>V</kbd> > <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>T</kbd> > <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard method to Copy and Paste Formatting in Excel 365:

1. Go to the cell whose format you want to copy.
2. Ctrl+C
3. Go to the cell or range where you want to paste only the format.
4. Shift+F10 R

Explanation of 4: Shift+F10 opens the context menu. R activates Paste FoRmating.